# Is there a solution to this kind of Magic numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

An integer n is a magic number if there exists $2$ positive integers $a$ and $b$ greater or equal to $2$ such that $n=a^b+b$. Does there exist $2018$ consecutive numbers where only $2015$ numbers are magic?

My attempt:

I found that there exists $2015$ consecutive magic numbers which are $$\left(a^\frac{2016!}{i}\right)^i+i$$ where $i$ varies from $2$ to $2016$.
But obviously the answer is missing the three integers non magic.

Comment: What do you mean by a magic number? Do you mean perfect numbers?

Comment: I explained what is meant by a magic number in the question above. Well apparently it is not a perfect number.

Comment: The obvious next question to ask is whether any of the integers before or after these $2015$ are magic numbers or not.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to prove and I am asking you to help me with.